# php mysql simplexml_load_string() error mysql_escape_string

Tags: mysql, xml, simplexml, php

I save a XML file content in *MySQL* database with:

```
$content = mysql_escape_string($content);
$insert = mysql_query("insert into $db_table_xml (url,content) values ('$url','$content')" ); 
//content type : TEXT in MySQL


simplexml_load_string($content);
```

it returns an error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 361: parser error :
>   AttValue: ' expected in
>   D:\mkw\dev\Web\PHPnow-1.5.6\htdocs\yt2\common.php
>   on line 84
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   D:\mkw\dev\Web\PHPnow-1.5.6\htdocs\yt2\common.php
>   on line 146
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   D:\mkw\dev\Web\PHPnow-1.5.6\htdocs\yt2\common.php
>   on line 146

Comment: `simplexml_load_string($content); ` is trying to read your escaped content, which turns it into invalid, xml.  try to escape the content to insert in your query in a different variable, so you can load the original content in as xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks to me like your variable $content contains single quotes that are affecting the termination of the string. This is what your can do if this is the case:

```
$content= addslashes($content);
```

Then you write this into your record.

Comment: oh,yes, $content contains single quotes . I can save it succeful in mysql db with  mysql_escape_string() , but when i mysql_fetch_row() it and try to parse it with simplexml_load_string(),some are ok and some are wrong.

Comment: thinks, everybody ! the code above are all right,i can save it in mysql succefully,the real question is the content type ("TEXT") !
TEXT in MySQL max length is 64k , and my content is more , so when i parse the content i fetch from db, it return error . and those's length less then 64k are ok.

Answer (score 0):

This error means it is not valid xml, inspect the xml file to see if there is anything wrong with it.

Look for line 361 in it, there is probably special character or similar error

Edit.

Obviously when you escape the xml, you introduced invalid characters in your xml,

use.

```
$content_escape = mysql_escape_string($content); 
$insert = mysql_query("insert into $db_table_xml (url,content) values ('$url','$content_escape')" );  //content type : TEXT in MySQL
```

now your $contents is not affected

Comment: yes,but how can i do when i fetch data from my database? it seems tha php doesn't have unescape function.

Comment: now i understand,then escaping is not the issue, maybe you can look for a different way to organize your data, if you have such large xml files, you should look if you need the actual complete file. Maybe you can look at patterns in the xml and organize the data in different mysql tables. so when you need to fetch something, you only get the data you need,